# Looping through an array to get data description attr in a video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, html5-video

Hi I'm trying to do a loop through an array to get data description attr from a video tag that it is being inserted once the user clicks to watch a video from a playlist however I'm getting undefined error. the code i am using is below. Can you help or maybe another way to access the data-description attribute.

```
var videoTitle = $('video-player').each(function(){
                  return $(this).attr('data-description');
                }).get().join(',');
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` gives you the collection of your selector and `"data-description"` is not a valid selector. However you have to iterate through the collection.

Comment: Can you give me some tips on how to do that?

Comment: can i use for each function like this?

var videoTitle = 'video news week' + 

          $(".video-tracking").each(function(num,val){
            console.log($(this).attr('data-description') );
              strText = $(this).attr('data-description'); 
              strlabel = strText.substring(0, strText);
          })